# Combining vector elements with paste

Tags: r, syntax, paste

I have two vectors:

```
old <- c("a", "b", "c")
new <- c("1", "2", "3")
```

I want to combine them, so that the elements of the new vector `var_names` are `'a' = '1'`, `'b' = '2'`, `'c' = '3'`.

I tried something like this:

```
for (i in length(new)){
    var_names[i] <- paste(old[i], "=", new[i])
}
```

But it is not working properly. What am I doing wrong here?

## EDIT

I was a bit unclear about this. But what I am trying to achieve is;

```
var_names<- c('a' = '1',
              'b' = '2',
              'c' = '3')
```

Reason: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#coef-map

Comment: `paste(old, new, sep = ' = ')` should work.

Comment: `paste(old,"=",new)
[1] "a = 1" "b = 2" "c = 3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically if you want quotes around a and b

```
paste0("'",old,"'"," = ","'",new,"'")
[1] "'a' = '1'" "'b' = '2'" "'c' = '3'"
```

If you want it all in one string

```
paste0("'",old,"'"," = ","'",new,"'",collapse=", ")
[1] "'a' = '1', 'b' = '2', 'c' = '3'"
```

**Edit:** regarding your edit, did you mean this?

```
names(new)=old
new
  a   b   c 
"1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I notice that I was a bit unclear about what I wanted to achieve. Please see my EDIT.

Comment: Yes, your edit works perfectly. I cannot believe it was so simple..

Answer (score 2):

### Update

According to your update, you can use `setNames`

```
> setNames(new, old)
  a   b   c
"1" "2" "3"
```

---

There are two places you have syntax/logic errors:

1. You didn't initialize a vector `var_name`
2. In `for` loop, you should use `1:length(new)`

Below is a correction and it works

```
var_names <- c()
for (i in 1:length(new)) {
  var_names[i] <- paste(old[i], "=", new[i])
}
```

and you will see

```
> var_names
[1] "a = 1" "b = 2" "c = 3"
```

---

A more efficient way to achieve the same result is using `paste` or `paste0`, e.g.,

```
> paste(old, new, sep = " = ")
[1] "a = 1" "b = 2" "c = 3"

> paste0(old, " = ", new)
[1] "a = 1" "b = 2" "c = 3"
```